# Checkboxes and Lists

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a list of items, where all these items can be either checked or unchecked. I want this UI window to pop up on top of my current window, kind of like [this](http://developer.android.com/images/radio_buttons.png) but with a "Submit" dialog instead.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own layout and use it for dialog (or even new popup-looking activity)